# Strange NullReferenceException when using Triggers

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, exception, xaml

I have a very simple `TabItem` template, and a single `MultiTrigger` with a `SourceName` attribute used on one `Condition`. The following XAML throws `NullReferenceException` when started, with no helpful info which would help me to fix the problem.

The strangest thing about this is the code works great if you remove the `SourceName` attribute. Or, if you leave the `SourceName` attribute, but remove `MultiTrigger.EnterActions` and use standard `Setter`s instead, then it works as well. Only the combination of `SourceName` attribute and `MultiTrigger.EnterActions` throws `NullReferenceException` for no obvious reason. So what's wrong with this?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                        <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                            <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard_TabItem_Hover">
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3" Value="0.1" />
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </ControlTemplate.Resources>

                        <Border x:Name="background" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" Background="Yellow">
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" />
                        </Border>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" SourceName="background" />
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

                                <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="sbHover" Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard_TabItem_Hover}"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <TabControl Margin="10">
        <TabItem Header="Tab 1" />
        <TabItem Header="Tab 2" />
        <TabItem Header="Tab 3" />
        <TabItem Header="Tab 4" />
    </TabControl>
</Window>
```

### Update

As [Greg Sansom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/503969/greg-sansom) [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493394/strange-nullreferenceexception-when-using-triggers/5493611#5493611), there is a simple workaround using `MultiDataTrigger` and `Binding`. However, I would still like to know why is the exception being thrown in the first place. I've searched Google and MSDN like crazy but haven't found anything. So what's the problem?

Comment: Have you found since a different solution/explanation? I have a similar problem with simple Triggers, which if converted to DataTrigger like Greg proposed, fixes my problem.  It happens with Visual Studio 2013's designer (runtime is fine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work around the problem by changing the MultiTrigger to a MultiDataTrigger, and specifying Binding instead of SourceName:

```
   <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=bg,Path=IsMouseOver}" 
Value="True"  />
        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
 Path=IsSelected}" Value="False" />
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! But do you know whats the problem with standard MultiTrigger and SourceName? Why is the exception being thrown?

Comment: I've searched the documentation and haven't found anything. Of course I'm fine with the solution, but I'm still learning WPF and want to have a deeper knowledge of how things work. So if anyone knows what's going on here, please let me know.